# Reading from text file and storing contents into a list Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, bufferedreader, stringbuilder

I have a text file that contains values in the following form and what I'm trying to do is to insert the two elements of each line into a list, but by removing the spaces that appear before the first element.

What I have (text file):

```
 290729 one
  79076 12345
  76789 hi
    462 nick
```

What I'm trying to do using the list:

```
[290729 one,79076 12345,76789 hi,462 nick]

instead of

[ 290729 one,  79076 12345,  76789 hi   ,    462 nick]
```

Is this a reasonable action or it is not necessary? The reason I'm asking is because I intent to use the two values of each line later on and I think since the spaces before the first value are not equal for every element of the list it might be a problem in picking the first value whereas all the second values have only one space before them.

Here is my code so far:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            list.add(line);             
        }
finally {
   br.close();
}
```

Comment: Looks like a simple `trim()` is all you need! `list.add(line.trim());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a simple `trim()` is all you need! `list.add(line.trim());`

Answer (score 1):

What I believe you need is to call the java string trim() method on the lines you gets.

Reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_trim.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can 'trim' whitespace from the start and end of strings using the 'trim' method:

line = line.trim();